# CORS preflight OPTIONS call fails with 403 in browser even though server allows OPTIONS and returns 200 with headers

Tags: javascript, axios, cors

NGINX server is configured to allow OPTIONS and return CORS headers.

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' '*' always;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' '*' always;
```

Testing OPTIONS returns **200 with proper headers** successfully.

[image: CORS OPTIONS test]

When I attempt a POST to the API locally from client JS code (axios) in my browser(Chrome, Firefox), the console reports the preflight call failed due to non 200/OK OPTIONS response.

[image: Browser console]

No additional headers or config is done via Axios

```
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      data: request,
      url: 'https://www.example.com'
    };

    axios(options)
      .then((res) => {
        // do stuff
    })
```

Browser shows the following request headers from the client JS code:

[image: req headers]

I cannot figure out why the OPTIONS call works manually as configured, but browsers receive an HTTP 403. Nowhere is the server configured to return 403.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the 1 missed domain, would you mind removing it please? I added request headers, but nothing stands out.